# Syntax Problems? Insert Into

Tags: mysql

I'm creating an online store/database in MySQL, and I'm fairly new to the system.
Please tell me what is wrong with this statement:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Customers (
ID INT(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  -- Connects to table 'Orders' andOrderUserID
Email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
PersonName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
City VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL,
Zip INT(10),
CustomerState VARCHAR(50),
Address VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
Country VARCHAR(20),
Phone INT(50),
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);


INSERT INTO Customers (ID, Email, PersonName, City, Zip, CustomerState, Address, Country, Phone) VALUES
(1, '1@gmail.com', 'Fred', 'Brisbane', 6543, 'QLD', '20 Not telling   avenue', 'Australia', 932363626),
(2, '2@gmail.com', 'Mark', 'Perth', 3212, 'WA', ' 122 cralic road', 'Australia', 93223463221),
(3, '3@gmail.com', 'Leo', 'Melbourne', 2342, 'VIC', '90 normanly drive', 'Australia', 932645321),
(4, '4@gmail.com', 'Nick', 'Perth', 4294, 'WA', '44 happylane drive', 'Australia', 932222565621),
(5, '5@gmail.com', 'Mary', 'Perth', 6383, 'WA', '3 iverno crescent', 'Australia', 93365543321),
(6, '6@gmail.com', 'Julie', 'Perth', 9563, 'WA', '100 richmane lane', 'Australia', 9323456421),
(7, '7@gmail.com', 'Cynthia', 'Hobart', 3456, 'TAS', '12 trump avenue', 'Australia', 9322364641),
(8, '8@gmail.com', 'Mike', 'Albany', 7544, 'WA', '23 mapatazzie road', 'Australia', 9322236421),
(9, '9@gmail.com', 'Brett', 'Adelaide', 8953, 'SA', '983 chindes lane', 'Australia', 9322234651),
(10, '10@gmail.com', 'Paul', 'Sydney', 7853, 'VIC', '78 yives road', 'Australia', 932223463621),
```

Comment: Last insert should terminate with ;

Comment: Replace the comma at the end of the `INSERT` with a semicolon

Comment: And phone is too big for an int field.

Comment: Just for info: some countries have phone numbers starting with 0, so better to use varchar for storing phone numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) Always post which error you get when asking for help

2.) You left a comma `,` at the last line

3.) `int(50)` does not do what you think it does. It doesn't mean a number that has 50 digits. `int` means data type, and it will use `4` bytes. `50`, in your case, means *display length*. Not **storage length**. `int` is 4 bytes. It can display up to 11 digits only (with minus sign included). Therefore, your `int(50)` doesn't make it 50 digits long, it will hold at maximum (2^32 - 1) = `4294967295`.

Make your `Phone` a `varchar`

Answer (score 0):

Update Last line with below line:

```
(10, '10@gmail.com', 'Paul', 'Sydney', 7853, 'VIC', '78 yives road', 'Australia', 932223463621);
```

add semicolon

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

The problem is, you mentioned Phone field as integer and given values like 93223463221.

The integer value is greater than **2147483647**, hence the error.

**To solve,**

```
alter table Customers modify column Phone varchar(50);
```

Use the above query to modify the Phone(Integer) filed as varchar field.

Then try to insert the values.